# Get AWS Iot CA Certificate Information

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I've automated creation of an IOT CA certificate, using the aws Java sdk. I'm now trying to automate the deletion of the created certificate. In order to differentiate between existing certificates and the ones i want to delete, each certificate subject CN attribute has been assigned a unique name.

Unfortunately, it seems impossible to accomplish the deletion, due to the fact the sdk provides no way of retrieving certificate subject and/or issuer attribute information.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly get the policy of the certificate, which can have rules based off the issuer and subject.  And so, you can delete any certificate which has a policy with "iot:Certificate.Subject" equal to X.  I'm looking into doing something similar and that's the best I can come up with.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/cert-policy-variables.html